# How to disable conversation threading in Outlook web app?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

The Outlook 2010 web app's conversation threading "feature" is really bugging me.

Is there any way to make it cease and desist (if so, how)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is, you need to:

- Click the drop down arrow next to `Arrange`
- Uncheck the box next to `Conversation`

If you are looking to do this globally across all users I think this is only available in SP1 via OWA Group Policies

Comment: Thanks!  I never thought to look under "arrange"!  I thought that was just for basic sorting.  I'd been hunting around in all the options and preferences screens I could find!

Comment: Thanks guys, that was helpful. Just a note: you need to go to each individual folder (inbox, sent, drafts, etc) and uncheck the "conversation" option under "Arrange by".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to click on the arrow next to "**Arrange by:**" and the current sort (e.g. "Arrange by: Date v" or "Arrange by: From v" where "v" is my lazy symbol for the down-pointing filled triangle).

Sorry if this is obvious to everyone other than me - but new interfaces do sometimes take time to get used to.

BTW if you're happy with conversation threading, wait until you get emails from a few different threads without any subject line and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find *Arrange* or *Arrange By*, but I did go under *View* when looking at my inbox (next to the New | Delete | Move | Filter) and unmarked the **Use conversations** option. You do need to select other folders to do the same thing (i.e. Sent items, drafts, etc.).